# OAuth2 Login Which Token gives User Details such as email, username

Tags: node.js, outlook, oauth-2.0, openid-connect

after a successfull login microsoft provides these token object

which token contains the user details and how to get it

```
{ token_type: 'Bearer',
  scope: 'https://outlook.office.com/Calendars.Read',
  expires_in: 3600,
  ext_expires_in: 0,
  access_token: 'EwAYA+l3BAAUWm1xSeJRIJK6txKjBez4GzapzqMAAYFVBgaTrs3ZosM0HnTxd3nZSpyA9h212p05Es5F4O/qr0XX7jhQ3jfJf0Ww
Ffl54ct01Np+4u+ldfxSPswK+6J6PamfZffkWDO72BRyd054NG5lM7cY8qQvuzSn3a9TUD1fw6P+jEO6B4pa7AgS9RfSAtTIXKyo98+r/Hog+uhjntHSc
X8waNI9MLaBpT36YerwbHnaQirB7zPvL9Fi0ghf0dPtbDfypYNO3STiP9rho8iwx3DwKRN0bgpq/7RV5+6NURqRCnAUJ7QOK7PUuDjx06EF+/BuagmNZw
tCgfcEKWb5ckfLI6BRw/adNKSy0olWNX7rWFUQ0Hiq7gVcpakDZgAACLL1KiAs58qo6AGeGvuV7Ur6tNDXPlpQlkqthOFYsdRvv+F2ycohaM86eYh++Xj
gdB4rQM/eI7/BFsVZ+bBJFY9BaIdPhkZC8VJNgmkXRtOqYI8PE35x1bcDSRXOfv9wO0PPmUn3eq3ptze9WnMaLR2oq0JLxl9/N9CUU2Vlvc8SX4mU7wZ5
8QDtXHNOElBtkVl98gvd4dmsUSQLmfKErAEanpPdWFKu4i1LFiMUG2rA5yaP3UuTjOxnjynSk7ltGblsTG85YQFR4yCBJYIIFe5PRyFJv1ey4dZvFuVmS
VqBTw9W9I78la5n+fKyAZAWvZJB54gJrSfgtnS/j2nMoRvvwtozVjoKVhF1J4ye/6MUVareo1jp+4G+MxBpltzgxGsDIoajcS/yUD2QxVNKY0pLYdaTIP
FBALCeXCOEqET8ulb36YdSjFWH4eIxsY0u1TjRN+mIezOpxywqz13FmqT9gZctM1Am87O+5RSuU/M5VEzeVkyGgIC9P9JRiTCT2o7hcWSb5lv+Hvs5ojF
1mgZIIDwqmBxBFwyiB/QFaJIaFTwSk7aKolUy5Jp4C7yeib60CYtKMddyWTpw+cFeZHZhkWVFqV5GR3RVVHXMjfATSUdmbdO9qnJsIPqCPF1MJrII5ZId
EEGPi1xyye0pqjSJ6RoC',
  refresh_token: 'MCYeZJGPBGuzpTTCZtD5rd*!ka96mfkBTiNfQOS1h41TA8PZ2*81snoU!FBIja8jW5bDRSngAyRiquz1SOLqJDSJz1SikdLA9gj
0knhfgMblCgcHq4uTCOavwMLFBKR1mCOYOQcRoVrul6rHl1IKVFD61dGXRWqqvvieS4fMN*8EfLzDJW6i09wjDFacV!q*qdU0IEG61yUk9RcrYQUx11CI
dLTWGhuo476TuzA!5IJIHLPY661r0Y8*KgIR0!ugRqtmZari5jqbBt252lABJKYtOxQrYHA23dz5ukIOpAu4oJMkIgu2xMAxpZSUS6rylNAnKYV42RWAs
g!7Rzo2LVye1Kj6Pqa*7rz9urHpIa8zTeLRE8gWs!q2x2j1MtMNOMGdBWG8KN!AVl6P2T9Nq69rBvIC3dFtHqqmCJbxgkIVq1w153RNWv3V9QLT4H2U6J
w$$',
  id_token: 'eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6IjFMVE16YWtpaGlSbGFfOHoyQkVKVlhlV01xbyJ9.eyJ2ZXIiOiIyLjAiLCJ
pc3MiOiJodHRwczovL2xvZ2luLm1pY3Jvc29mdG9ubGluZS5jb20vOTE4ODA0MGQtNmM2Ny00YzViLWIxMTItMzZhMzA0YjY2ZGFkL3YyLjAiLCJzdWIi
OiJBQUFBQUFBQUFBQUFBQUFBQUFBQUFQMXEtSzhiVXRjaGhJdzE1aTdjU2VVIiwiYXVkIjoiOWUwN2U3N2ItMzdlYi00MGQ0LTg3NTctNTYzMTY3OTU0M
Dg0IiwiZXhwIjoxNDg3NjYyOTQ5LCJpYXQiOjE0ODc1NzYyNDksInRpZCI6IjkxODgwNDBkLTZjNjctNGM1Yi1iMTEyLTM2YTMwNGI2NmRhZCJ9.d6ApS
kc0v74n4gTyy4v8Vo1aMokKnMuAaFpy71jHawvTNbFMeU_Fq0jtbjKYuzujIZV9jIGBjSlADcgIg2mQHhqvKWAPzoEUbxhnin4GN0XM9_XMCjQG6yBkhB
tJ8nk6mmqhfr-OvHGoFXOgLeFbkf0i8TJYuMmtnzUeDQQnOtihFQCJvy4agh2aiKG5IZaOR87I2DQ1is-6m3hFexKLLKwxDMjRmIHAaAm8uXrxGLGABJm
EJCybmF2jorhzmZ_qbmBVJXSy1DESgYf5CW9owwKnJA2taQQ3Hd472qHQ0Xay9XXSJMn94HwiK07DWQXIjP3F0nhND1o2R_61Rgju6g',
  expires_at: 2017-02-20T08:42:30.061Z }
```

decoding `id_token`
it gives

```
{ ver: '2.0',
  iss: 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/9188040d-6c67-4c5b-b112-36a304b66dad/v2.0',
  sub: 'AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAP1q-K8bUtchhIw15i7cSeU',
  aud: '9e07e77b-37eb-40d4-8757-563167954084',
  exp: 1487664645,
  iat: 1487577945,
  tid: '9188040d-6c67-4c5b-b112-36a304b66dad' }
```

but it doesn't provide user details

or i have take some id and and call microsoft api's to get data

Comment: Can you please elaborate your question in terms of the context ?

Answer (score 1):

The Id Token is the only token that will give you information about the user.
It contains at least the user unique ID: the `sub` claim.

The ID Token may contain additional information such as its addresses, phones, emails and so on but **it depends on the Identity Provider policy**.

In general and as per the [OpenID Connect specification section 5.4](http://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#ScopeClaims), information can be retrieve using the following scopes.

- `profile`: gives the username, gender, birthdate...
- `email`: the emails
- `address`: the addresses
- `phone`: phone numbers

I do not know the Microsoft policy regarding these scopes. It is possible that, even if they are included in you authorization request, the additional information is not set in the ID Token

Comment: You would need to request scopes like this to get profile information: `"openid profile email https://outlook.office.com/Calendars.Read"`